# How to pick right uri scheme for intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I am going through Android's documentation but it looks like I am missing something. I don't know how to find which data Uri should I use with Intent actions.

So according to the documentation Intent has two primary information fields:

> **action** -- The general action to be performed, such as ACTION_VIEW,
> ACTION_EDIT, ACTION_MAIN, etc.
>
> **data** -- The data to operate on, such as
> a person record in the contacts database, expressed as a Uri. Some
> examples of action/data pairs are:
>
> ACTION_VIEW content://contacts/people/1 -- Display information about
> the person whose identifier is "1".
>
> ACTION_DIAL content://contacts/people/1 -- Display the phone dialer with the
> person filled in.
> ACTION_VIEW tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with
> the given number filled in. Note how the VIEW action does what what is
> considered the most reasonable thing for a particular URI.
>
> ACTION_DIAL> tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in.
>
> ACTION_EDIT content://contacts/people/1 -- Edit information about the
> person whose identifier is "1".

Finding Action is easy, but I have a trouble finding Uri that matches it.

Comment: What actions are you interested in? Some do not use a `Uri`. The values that the other actions use for a `Uri` will vary by the action.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: For example ACTION_VIEW. How am I supposed to know that I should specify "content://contacts/people/1" to see a person with id 1? What if I want to see the email, or phone number, or something else?